# Sign of a quadratic form on a real vector plane is mainly controlled by the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, determinant, quadratic-forms

The following claim is in the text of the book I am reading on Differential Geometry (*Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd Edition, by Montiel and Ros):

> It is a matter of elementary linear algebra that the sign of a quadratic form on a real vector plane is mainly controlled by its determinant.

What does this mean, precisely? How to prove this?

The context is the definition of elliptic and hyperbolic points on a surface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sign of a quadratic form is asking whether $Q(v)$ is always positive, always negative, or positive and negative, as $v$ varies over all nonzero vectors in the plane. We call these positive-definite, negative-definite, and indefinite respectively, and it is not hard to see that these correspond to having both eigenvalues positive, both negative, or one positive and one negative. (When thinking of $Q$ as a symmetric matrix). So a positive determinant means one of the two definite cases (you can use the trace of the matrix to tell them apart), and a negative determinant means indefinite.

Comment: Another point is that if you start on a positive-definite symmetric matrix and continuously vary the matrix, you will have to cross through something of determinant zero before getting to the indefinite and negative-definite cases. This argument is sometimes used in differential geometry, where the quadratic form is varying over points in the surface, and this could be what the “mainly” refers to, but it’s hard to tell without more context.

Comment: I understand now, and I am very thankful. Would you like to gather your comments togheter in an answer so I can upvote and accept it?